# How will to integrate the email calendar event entry in android programmatically?

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar

Here I want to make the event entry in a calendar programmatically but it should be the same as the Gmail event creation.

Like we can add gest to the event and if the event change by creator then the notification will go to the gest of the event.

Please help me to get this on android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for that and that is related to add attendees to the event.
And we can add the attendees to the particular event and that event mail will be sent to the attendee as well as to the organizer and also sent the mail if event edited or attendee response to the event.

#### Add the attendee to the event

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_NAME, "Trevor");
values.put(CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_EMAIL, "example@gmail.com");
values.put(CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_RELATIONSHIP, CalendarContract.Attendees.RELATIONSHIP_ATTENDEE);
values.put(CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_TYPE, CalendarContract.Attendees.TYPE_OPTIONAL);
values.put(CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_STATUS, CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_STATUS_INVITED);
values.put(CalendarContract.Attendees.EVENT_ID, eventId);
getContentResolver().insert(CalendarContract.Attendees.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

I hope this will help you to get that in android.